# Scrolling issue with a div inside a dialog

Tags: html, css, jquery-dialog

I created a div inside a jQuery dialog and I want this div to have a vertical scrollbar. For some reason, the content doesn't scroll. It just keeps going.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<input type="button" value="open" id="btnOpen">
<div id="myDialog">
    <div style="width: 350px; display: inline-table; overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px; margin-right: 50px;" id="divAvailableHosts">
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    test<br />test<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

I also create [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6y87o2sh/1/) demonstrating the issue.

Comment: Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/6y87o2sh/2/). is that you wanted???

Comment: @lal - No. All you are doing is changing the size of the dialog. I want the dialog to be 800px. I just want the div inside the dialog to be smaller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/lalu050/6y87o2sh/4/).

You just remove the `display:inline-table` from the style like

```
<div style="width: 350px;overflow-y: scroll; height: 200px; margin-right: 50px;" id="divAvailableHosts">
```

Comment: See my comment up above

Comment: That's what I wanted! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make the height of the div less then the content.